# ActivityManager ,moveTaskToFront ,Warning :Task to front request from 10040 stopped

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to use the method of ActivityManager.moveTaskToFront(int taskId, int flags),but not success
and get the warning,***Task to front request from 10040 stopped***, the source code is following:

```
List<TaskDescription> taskDescriptionsList = new ArrayList<TaskDescription>();
taskDescriptionsList = getRecentTasks();
TaskDescription taskDescription = taskDescriptionsList.get(0);

if (taskDescription.taskId >= 0) {
   final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   am.moveTaskToFront(taskDescription.taskId,ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
}else {
       Intent intent = taskDescription.intent;
       intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTOR
            |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

TaskDescription:

```
public final class TaskDescription {
final ResolveInfo resolveInfo;
final int taskId; // application task id for curating apps
final int persistentTaskId; // persistent id
final Intent intent; // launch intent for application
final String packageName; // used to override animations (see onClick())
final CharSequence description;

private Bitmap mThumbnail; // generated by Activity.onCreateThumbnail()
private Drawable mIcon; // application package icon
private CharSequence mLabel; // application package label

public TaskDescription(int _taskId, int _persistentTaskId,
        ResolveInfo _resolveInfo, Intent _intent,
        String _packageName, CharSequence _description) {
    resolveInfo = _resolveInfo;
    intent = _intent;
    taskId = _taskId;
    persistentTaskId = _persistentTaskId;

    description = _description;
    packageName = _packageName;
}

// mark all these as locked?
public CharSequence getLabel() {
    return mLabel;
}

public void setLabel(CharSequence label) {
    mLabel = label;
}

public Drawable getIcon() {
    return mIcon;
}

public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
    mIcon = icon;
}

public void setThumbnail(Bitmap thumbnail) {
    mThumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public Bitmap getThumbnail() {
    return mThumbnail;
}
}
```

How to solve this?